# How to say the equivalent of "to talk" or "to speak a language"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was wondering how one would say the equivalent of "to talk" or "to speak"?

Google seems to think it is "Dicere", though other sources seem to differ

For contextual information, I'm after a translation in relation to "speaking a language" or "to speak a language"

Wondering what is most commonly used in this instance

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the site! Latin, like English and I presume most other languages, has quite a few words to indicate talking. In the context of "to speak a language" (which, by the way, doesn't work with "talk"), the most common form is the verb ***loqui***. This is the infinitive form, equivalent to the English "to speak" as in "I want to speak Latin." That sentence would be *Latine loqui volo.*

*Loqui* is also the normal word for *to converse*. So if I wanted to say, "I am talking with you," you could say, *tecum loquor.*

The verb *dicere* is chiefly used of saying things. So to *say a word* would be *verbum dicere*.

Note that if you wanted to use *loqui* in a particular way, it conjugates similarly to a passive verb, yet is active in meaning. To see the full paradigm, check out the charts on [Wiktionary: loquor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loquor).

Comment: Thank you cmw! Would you be able to tell me what "to talk" or "talk" (in the sense of a giving a command to say "talk") would be?

Comment: The imperative of *loqui* is *loquere* for one person and *loquimini* for more than one person. Likewise, for *dicere*, it would be *dic* and *dicite* respectively.

Comment: apologies for the silly questions! the following is then a correct summary?

loquere -> speak (a command to a single person),
loquimini -> speak (command to more than one),
dic -> tell/say,
dicite -> tell/say (more than one)

Comment: @silent This is correct, but again, be careful with "speak." "to speak a language" is very different from "to speak what's on your mind."

Comment: In that case would "loquere" still be valid in the sense of commanding someone to "speak a language"?

Comment: @silent Yes, that's right.

Comment: thank you for your time! :)